# unable to run downloaded llama model

Tags: llama, llama-cpp-python, llamacpp

I'm trying to setup my local environment to use my llama model but get an error saying "Failed to load model from file"

```
from llama_cpp import Llama
llm = Llama(model_path='/Users/rem/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--TheBloke--Llama-2-13B-Ensemble-v5-GGUF',
            gqa=8)
output = llm(
      "Q: Name the planets in the solar system? A: ", # Prompt
      max_tokens=32, # Generate up to 32 tokens, set to None to generate up to the end of the context window
      stop=["Q:", "\n"], # Stop generating just before the model would generate a new question
      echo=True # Echo the prompt back in the output
)
```

The models are located in the same path, here is the output of scan-cache

```
(ms-nlp) REMs-MacBook-Pro:m3g prem$ huggingface-cli scan-cache
REPO ID                               REPO TYPE SIZE ON DISK NB FILES LAST_ACCESSED  LAST_MODIFIED  REFS LOCAL PATH                                                                        
------------------------------------- --------- ------------ -------- -------------- -------------- ---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TheBloke/Llama-2-13B-Ensemble-v5-GGUF model              0.0        0 10 minutes ago 29 minutes ago main /Users/rem/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--TheBloke--Llama-2-13B-Ensemble-v5-GGUF 
TheBloke/Llama-2-13B-GGUF             model              0.0        0 10 minutes ago 3 hours ago    main /Users/rem/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--TheBloke--Llama-2-13B-GGUF             
TheBloke/Llama-2-7b-Chat-GGUF         model              0.0        0 3 hours ago    3 hours ago    main /Users/rem/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--TheBloke--Llama-2-7b-Chat-GGUF         

Done in 0.0s. Scanned 3 repo(s) for a total of 0.0.
```